# Laravel 5.1 using storage to move the file to a public folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

In my Laravel API call, I use Storage to upload a file.  Then I wold like to rename and move the file to a public directory by using:

```
    $dest = '/var/www/public/uploads/';
    Storage::disk('local')->put($filename.'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
    $oldfilename = $filename.'.'.$extension;
    Storage::move($oldfilename, $dest.$newImageName);
```

But instead of moving the file to the $dest directory, I get a folder created with the $dest dir name inside my storage/app folder and the file is copied there.  I have also tried using double quotes around `$dest.$newImageName` but no success.

Comment: Chang $dest = '/var/www/public/uploads/';  to $dest = 'uploads/';

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an array `['disks']['public']` in *config/filesystems.php* you can do:

```
Storage::disk('public')->move($oldfilename, $dest.$newImageName);
```

If you don't create one that looks like this:

```
    'public' => [
        'driver'     => 'local',
        'root'       => storage_path( 'app/public' ),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

And then you'll bi able to use the *public* "disk" with the storage facade.

Note that you don't have to specify the absolute path anymore, Laravel will know that the storage path is *app/public*.

**EDIT**

Another config option that might work:

```
    'public' => [
        'driver'     => 'local',
        'root'       => public_path(),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: The code above puts the file in myappname/storage/public/  What I really want to do is put the file in myappname/public folder.. where we store index.php and .robots.txt

Comment: If the answer wasn't what you wanted, why did you accepted this answer then?

Answer (score 0):

This method is for when your host is cPanel and the terminal feature is available.

first go to your config>filesystems.php

the last line is like this:

```
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

you should change it to your host public_html path like this :

```
'links' => [
    '/home/NAME/public_html/storage' => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

you can find the "NAME" in you host root folder.

go to cPanel terminal
cd to your project file.
by ls command you can see the children of the root your command line is.
run command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

NOTE: you should remove the public_html>storage folder (if exist) before run the command above.